# Write the data incoming from Python Socket to a file

Tags: python, byte, decode

I am receiving data coming from ethernet using Python sockets. The incoming data is raw (not encoded, plain hex data) and I want to write it into a file as it is. Socket `recv` method returns `bytes` type, and assume received data is 10 bytes `b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09'`, what I want to do is to write it into a file in the fastest way possible (data is streaming with 700 Mbit/sec throughput) byte by byte (or maybe bit by bit) in plain form not decoded.

The resulting file should look like this:

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
```

When I print the data, I see `b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t'`, when I print data.decode() I see blank (when data is for example b'\x41', and I print it using .decode, I see character A because it is decoded).

Here is my code to test the print:

```
data = []
for i in range(10):
    data.append(i)
data = bytes(data)
print(data)
print(data.decode())

a = b'\x41'
print(a)
print(a.decode())
```

Comment: Just open your file in binary mode (e.g., 'wb' if you're creating a new file) then simply write whatever you get from *recv()*

Comment: I agree with _OldBill_. You can make each line have a single byte as hex, like so: `f.write("".join(f"{byte:02x}\n" for byte in data).encode())`

Comment: @OldBill I check the resulting text file with format-hex utility of PowerShell and it works, thanks!

Comment: @GordonAitchJay the ```.encode()``` makes it encoded, as I stated before I need plain text.

Comment: @efe373 Yes, `.encode()` returns an encoded version of the string as a `bytes` object. When writing a file in binary mode, you are writing `bytes`, not `str`. I'm not sure what you mean by "plain text". When the first byte of data is `\x00`, do you want that saved as null or 00?